# Will every information stored in session object be passed to client in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, omniauth

I am trying to implement Omniauth. I would like to store user's login information from a third party (like Facebook email) to session temporarily, like:

```
session[:email] = auth.email
```

Will this information be automatically passed to client?

I know that session ID will be passed to client, but not sure if it is the case for other objects in session.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what session store you have selected.  If you have selected `cookie` as the session store, it will put all session data in the cookie, which would involve sending it to the client.  Otherwise, it just stores the key in the cookie, since that is all that is needed to identify the user and get their session data.

Answer (score 1):

The data you put into the session hash will be stored on client side, but it will be encrypted using your `secret_token`. If you want to see what's in your session, you can grab the session data out of your browser, then do:

```
Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(session_data))
```

The above will show you exactly what you're storing in the browser's session.

Comment: Thanks for the `decode` tip, gylaz. I accepted Scott's answer b/c he pointed out that I can choose not to store data in cookie but in session database.